# Can't get current location when offline Windows 10 App?

Tags: geolocation, windows-10, tablet, uwp

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to get the current location of a Windows 10 device if it's not connected to the internet via Wi-Fi (Wi-Fi) is disabled . I'm aiming this at Windows 10tablets and I don't think they all support GPS. Does anyone know what would be the best way to go about this? Or is it possible at all? 
when i use  Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
it returns Exception  .

Comment: You would like to know device's position without using *WiFi* and *GPS*?

Comment: what exception you got?

Comment: i'd like to get device position with GPS only.   WiFi is disabled or enabled and  no available networks .

Comment: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE7

Comment: Issue Resolved ..   after activation for GNSS Service from network settings  get current location and updates accurately .