# How to solve System exception on button click while trying to access location?

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2015, async-await, iot

I am new to visual studio and developing universal windows applications. My program throws an exception when I click a UI button that should display location information on click. It is a UWP. The location access is turned on from the package manifest.
The code looks like this:

```
private async void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var geoLocator = new Geolocator();
            geoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            Geoposition positionInfo = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            string latitude = "Latitude: " + positionInfo.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString();
            string longitude = "Longitude: " + positionInfo.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }


    }
```

The exception stacktrace is as below:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE7
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at HelloLocation.MainPage.<getBtn_Click>d__1.MoveNext()
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE7
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at HelloLocation.MainPage.d__1.MoveNext()
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE7
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at HelloLocation.MainPage.<getBtn_Click>d__1.MoveNext()
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE7
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at HelloLocation.MainPage.d__1.MoveNext()
>   The program '[3032] hellolocation.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Have you tried calling the method synchronously? Instead of using await x.GetGeoPositionAsync(), use: y = x.GetGeoPosition[Async]()[.Result]; See if that changes something.

Comment: @Beatsleigher I tried using the exact same code you suggested, but it throws an error :
Error CS1061 'Geolocator' does not contain a definition for 'GetGeoPosition' and no extension method 'GetGeoPosition' accepting a first argument of type 'Geolocator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first request access, and then use the result from this request to determine if you can attempt to use the `GetGeopositionAsync` call.

Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
...
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
switch (accessStatus) {
 case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:

  // If DesiredAccuracy or DesiredAccuracyInMeters are not set (or value is 0), DesiredAccuracy.Default is used.
  Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = _desireAccuracyInMetersValue };

  // Subscribe to StatusChanged event to get updates of location status changes
  _geolocator.StatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;

  try {                        
   // Carry out the operation
   Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   // handle the exception (notify user, etc.)
  }
  break;

 case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
  // handle access denied case here
  break;

 case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
  // handle unspecified error case here
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I tried this way but it still throws exception as follows:    Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE7
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at HelloLocation.MainPage.<getBtn_Click>d__1.MoveNext()
The program '[3736] hellolocation.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Does your application manifest have the geolocation or location checked as capabilities?

Comment: Does the `accessStatus` come back as `GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed` or does it throw on that request?

Comment: The `accessStatus` is allowed. It throws on the `await`.

Comment: Go to activation for GNSS Service from network settings get current location and updates accurately :: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33391228/2410379

Comment: I did not exactly follow the thread. Can you please tell me where I can activate the GNSS Service or where is the network settings? Thank you for your help:)

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/221869/how-to-disable-or-configure-location-tracking-in-windows-10/

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/petrsimon/geolocationtcp/issues/9/windows-10-gnss-status-not-properly

Comment: Oh.. The location is turned on for my PC and I can see that my application has location enabled. I did not understand that you meant this earlier.Sorry! No luck yet:( I am trying on my PC now, so maybe I will switch it to my phone and try.

Comment: It works now. :) I had been working with a visual studio running on a virtual machine earlier. I guess it doesn't have the required permission to access location even though location was enabled in both real (my PC) and virtual machine. I used the same code with another laptop directly without a virtual machine and it works perfectly well ! Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. :) I had been working with a visual studio running on a virtual machine earlier. I guess it doesn't have the required permission to access location even though location was enabled in both real (my PC) and virtual machine. 
I used the same code with another laptop directly without a virtual machine and it works perfectly well !